# Is it possible to configure a date picker to compare months instead of days?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to configure a date picker to compare months instead of days ? Does anyone have any links ...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "compare". Can you give an example or two?

Comment: I have List in sharepoint that currently uses the date column to compare one date against another for 2 datepickers. However id now like to compare month against month... anyway to set date picker to months

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using a date picker library and you can get two separate dates, you could do something like this:

```js
function sameMonth(d1, d2) {
  // Ensure we got two Date objects.
  if (!d1 || !d2 || (d1.constructor != Date) || (d1.constructor != Date)) {
    return false;
  }
  // Ensure they have the same year and month.
  return (d1.getFullYear() == d2.getFullYear()) &&
         (d1.getMonth() == d2.getMonth());
}

// Example usage.
var d1 = new Date("2001-01-11T00:00:00Z")
  , d2 = new Date("2001-01-22T12:34:56Z")
  , d3 = new Date("1980-01-01T00:00:00Z");
sameMonth(d1, d1); // => true
sameMonth(d1, d2); // => true
sameMonth(d1, d3); // => false
```